# Fusion Guest OS Opening Files In Host OS

Tags: macos, vmware

MacBook Pro Early 2011 - Mac OSX 10.7.2
VMWare Fusion 4.0.2
Guest OS is Win7 64-bit, all the latest updates.  MS Office 2010 w/latest.

So, basically I'm using the Win7 guest OS for Outlook only (I need to run Taglocity, which doesn't work with Mac Office 2011).  Anyway, when I get emailed a URL I can click on it and the URL is opened in my default browser on the Host OS.  Love it!  I want to do the same thing for documents that I receive.  I want to be able to open an email attachment that is a PDF, DOCX, PPTX, etc. and have it open in the host appropriate Mac OSX app.  I feel like I should be able to do this, but can't quite get my mind around it.

In Fusion Preferences > Default Applications I have checked "Open your Windows files and Web links using Mac applications".  The second part of the "Web links" works fine.  But not the first!

Edit: I should also say that VMware tools are installed!

Can anyone help me out here?  How can I get my Host apps to be associated with file types in my Windows guest?

Answer (score 1):

It should work automatically.  Try upgrading to Fusion 4.1.2.  Be sure to update the VMware Tools, too.